# Matplotlib: multiple 3D lines all get drawn using the final y-value in my loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to plot multiple lines in a 3D figure. Each line represents a month: I want them displayed parallel in the y-direction.

My plan was to loop over a set of Y values, but I cannot make this work properly, as using the ax.plot command (see working code below) produces a dozen lines *all at the position of the final Y value*. Confusingly, swapping ax.plot for ax.scatter *does* produce a set of parallel lines of data (albeit in the form of a set of dots; ax.view_init set to best display the parallel aspect of the result).

**How can I use a produce a plot with multiple parallel lines?** 
My current workaround is to replace the loop with a dozen different arrays of Y values, and that *can't* be the right answer.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# preamble
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cs = ['r','g','b','y','r','g','b','y','r','g','b','y']

# x axis
X = np.arange(24)

# y axis
y = np.array([15,45,75,105,135,165,195,225,255,285,315,345])
Y = np.zeros(24)

# data - plotted against z axis
Z = np.random.rand(24)

# populate figure
for step in range(0,12):
    Y[:] = y[step]
#    ax.plot(X,Y,Z, color=cs[step])
    ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, color=cs[step])

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
# set initial view of plot
ax.view_init(elev=80., azim=345.)
plt.show()
```

I'm still learning python, so simple solutions (or, preferably, those with copious explanatory comments) are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ax.plot(X, np.array(Y), Z, color=cs[step])
```

or

```
Y = [y[step]] * 24
```

This looks like a bug in mpl where we are not copying data when you hand it in so each line is sharing the same `np.array` object so when you update it *all* of your lines.

Comment: Wow - a brilliantly simple solution (two, in fact!) - thank you very much, that's perfect.